# index scan and implicit or explicit data convesion

Tags: sql-server

I was looking some of our execution plan on production databases where ever there is convert function be it implicit or explicit there is an index scan,

is it safe to say that these convert function always lead to index scan

Answer (score 0):

Refereed to this site, there is an article by Jonathan Kehayias https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/jonathan/implicit-conversions-that-cause-index-scans/